# How to use Multiple-Domains in one Multi-Site Installation?

Tags: multisite, domain

I have created a Multi-Site and want to help my friends to create Sub-sites under it.I also have Idea to offer 3 choices to chose from the domain names they wish .

> For Example :
>          My main site is mydomain.com .They should have an option to chose
>   from domain1.com,domain2.com and
>   domain3.com .

I have googled for any instructions on it and got this one on [wpmudev](http://premium.wpmudev.org/project/multi-domains).But I would like to set this functionality with any plugin which I can get free of cost or configuring  manually .Do any one Implemented this ever before? Once I read similar questions some where but I have not find a right solution .

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, Multi-Domains from WPMUDEV is the only plugin which works flawlessly with the lastest version of WordPress. It is BuddyPress compatible, has a single signon and even a multi-subdomain feature (blog1.subdomain.site.com, blog2.subdomain.site.com).

There is a free alternative, but it has not been updated for the latest version of WordPress (the author is not currently available to do it) and it is not as full featured as the wpmudev plugin.
http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/yet-another-multi-site-manager/
You may want to download it and modify it to fix the issues with WordPress 3.0.

Comment: Yeah ! I have tried yet-another-multi-site-manager.But I have deactivated it as I have got a conflict problem with other plugin once.

Comment: Could you tell me If any other people using it(YAMM)?

Comment: No, I don't know any other people using it. When I tested, it seemed to work correctly (it was a quick test). May be you would want to use it and find a fix to the conflict with the other plugin...

Answer (score 2):

Isn't this what [WordPress MU Domain Mapping (Wordpress Plugin)](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wordpress-mu-domain-mapping/) is dealing with?

Comment: I am not talking about donncha's Domain mapping plugin . I need to let my users to select the domain they wish to publish the blog.I mean that they would have an option to chose a domain other the default one during the sign up itself .