# How To Provide Sub-Blogs Their Own Domain Names?

Tags: multisite, options, domain, customization

I ran a search that did not yield that many results.

Is it possible, and how can each sub-blog of a multi-site installation be given its own domain name?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Shortly after, I was able to find Otto's tutorial on the topic.

[WordPress 3.0: Multisite Domain Mapping Tutorial](http://ottopress.com/2010/wordpress-3-0-multisite-domain-mapping-tutorial/)

Answer (score 4):

for reference, see also:

1. [How to use Multiple-Domains in one Multi-Site Installation?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/1362/how-to-use-multiple-domains-in-one-multi-site-installation)
2. [301 Redirects for posts, category, pages from original domain to sub-domain of multisite](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/3636/301-redirects-for-posts-category-pages-from-original-domain-to-sub-domain-of-mu)
3. [Full Domain Mapping with WP3 in Multiuser Mode](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/854/full-domain-mapping-with-wp3-in-multiuser-mode)